# Class definition with required_arg, *args, **kwargs

Tags: python, class, arguments

II would like use one required_arg in addition to  *args, **kwargs in a class coming from one other class. But currently I do not succeed!!!
The piece of code:

```
class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    "For  add \"page number of total\" in each footer."

    def __init__(self, page1, *args, **kwargs):
        "Constructor."
        self.page1 = page1 - 1
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []
```

The error message when I do: `canvasmaker = PageNumCanvas(1)`:

```
canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How I can call the PageNumCanvas class with the `page1` argument?

Update #1:

If I do not use argument in the **init** of the class I have no problem. Ex:

```
>>> from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
>>> class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
...     "For  add \"page number of total\" in each footer."
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...             canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
...             self.pages = []
... 
>>> canvasmaker = PageNumCanvas(1)
>>> canvasmaker
<__main__.PageNumCanvas instance at 0x7f618195df38>
>>>
```

Update #2:
Thanks to goncalopp that gave the way, the correct code is:

```
class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
...     "For  add \"page number of total\" in each footer."
...     def __init__(self, page1, *args, **kwargs):
...             "Constructor."
...             canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, page1, *args, **kwargs)
...             self.page1 = page1 - 1
...             self.pages = []
...             print self.page1
... 
>>> canvasmaker = PageNumCanvas(12)
11
>>>
```

Comment: Can only guess without knowing what the `__init__()` method for `class canvas.Canvas` looks like.

Comment: See edited answer, that should solve it, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, page1, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the example [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/reportlab/3.1.8/reportlab.pdfgen.textobject/), you need to provide a name when you instantiate `canvas.Canvas()`.

The reason your second version does not give you an error is that you are still passing the `1` which gets passed on to the `Canvas` constructor because you removed the `page1` argument.

In order to make it work, you simply need to pass in a name as well as a page number:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    "For  add \"page number of total\" in each footer."

    def __init__(self, page1, *args, **kwargs):
        "Constructor."
        self.page1 = page1 - 1
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []

canvasmaker = PageNumCanvas(1, "Hello.pdf")
print canvasmaker.page1
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Comment: @ SiHa: Arggghhh !!!I do not succeed to add code in comment !!! So I adds update #1 in the original question. It is just for illustrate that if I do not define the argument page1 in the __init__ of the class,  I have no problem. So I think I do not need to use  PageNumCanvas(1, master, 'MyCanvasName') ? Thanks for your suggestion /help.

Comment: My first answer was based on thinking you were talking about Tkinter Canvas. Now you've added your second example, it's obvious I was wrong. The above should work (it does for me).